# CentO7 multiple TCP port forwarding entries, does not allow certain ports

Tags: iptables, kvm-virtualization, centos7

I have CentOS7 KVM setup that is using TCP port forwarding to forward SSH sessions to three guests running behind a NAT virtual bridge.

This is the setup i'm looking establish

`2020 -> 192.168.100.10`
`2021 -> 192.168.100.11`
`2022 -> 192.168.100.12`

This is the command I am using

`iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d $host --dport 2020 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.100.10:22
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d $host --dport 2021 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.100.11:22
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d $host --dport 2022 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.100.12:22
iptables -I FORWARD -m state -d 192.168.100.0/24 --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`

Here's the interesting observation

Port 2020, and 2021 works, port 2022 does not. Below is the result of running a port scanner from another host

`$ nc -z -v -w5 acn1 2020
Connection to acn1 2020 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
$ nc -z -v -w5 acn1 2021
Connection to acn1 2021 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
$ nc -z -v -w5 acn1 2022
nc: connect to acn1 port 2022 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress`

From the host, I can SSH to 192.168.100.12 fine, and I don't see any other services using the port 2020.

This is the output of my /etc/sysconfig/iptables. I am running the port forwarding script separately from the iptables.service

`*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [214:43782]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
COMMIT`

Comment: "but I notice only 20 of these entries are working" how exactly you have checked?

Comment: I checked all 40 connections using port scanner, only of the 20 ports were open

Comment: What's the "-m tcp" for? I'm unaware that this is necessary for forwarding. "-t nat" seems to be missing though.

Comment: @AndreasM, thats the output of "iptables -t nat -S". The command i use to add the entry is "iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp -d $host --dport $SSH -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.100.$now:22"

Comment: I see, thanks. Are the corresponding ports on the filter (-t filter -A INPUT) opened?

Comment: Yes, according to the output of "iptables -t filter -S", port range 2020 to 3000 are open.`-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2020:3000 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT`

Comment: I have updated the issue. I reduced the number of vm's down to 3 and noticed the issue seems to be forwarding to certain ports. The same setup works for my ubuntu development system but not on CentOS7, any thoughts?